# Patrol: Allow Modify System Settings in Android

Tags: android, flutter, integration-testing, gui-testing

I'm using patrol for writing UI tests in flutter, in android version, the app uses "android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS", which should be allowed by the user, through the following screen:
[allow writing system settings screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZoeJ.png)

How to turn on the toggle switch using patrol?

I used:

```
  await $.native.grantPermissionWhenInUse();
```

but I got:
`The following PatrolActionException was thrown running a test: Patrol action failed: NativeAutomatorClientException: grantPermissionWhenInUse() failed with Invalid response: 404 selector button to allow permission while using found nothing`

While I was expecting granting writing permission.

Answer (score 0):

```
await $.native.tap(Selector(text: 'Allow modifying system settings'));
```

The details could be found here: https://patrol.leancode.co/tips-and-tricks#granting-sensitive-permission-through-the-settings-app

Comment: Thanks, I tried using it, but the app freezes, see the issue: https://github.com/leancodepl/patrol/issues/2041

Comment: you might provide patrol team the minimal example app so they can reproduce and fix. Could you try on a real device, it works normally here.